# How can I watch log messages as they are written?

Tags: debugging, operating-system

I am debugging a new application that is crashing. I want to watch the messages as they are being written to the log. What command should I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on a unixy system and your log is a file, you want `tail -f <filename>`.

If you're on a Windows system, there are [ports of `tail`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) available (hat tip - Dave Webb).

Comment: There are various ports of tail available for Windows systems.  For example - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: Similarly, I've had great luck on Windows with http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac OS X, run Console (in /Applications/Utilities). It is a nice GUI for viewing and searching logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)

It's a small executable that doesn't need to be installed and runs on Windows.  It has a tabbed interface so you can have several different files open at once.  You can also color code certain keywords in the logs.  All in all, a very handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer GUI tools, [jEdit](http://jedit.org/) has a [Log Viewer](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?LogViewer) plugin that may do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Dominic's answer, if you're on a Windowsy system, you can get Cygwin32, which will give you a tail command for Windows.  (And a bunch of other good stuff...)

Comment: it's preferable to get msys, as they are native windows ports.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tail -f log_file_name &
```

This would keep running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin and utilities on Windows and run

```
tail -f ./logfile
```

Cygwin gives you a unix like interface on Windows and provides you with most of the utilities as present on unix

Answer (score 0):

if it's for windows, try LogExpert, it's a lot like Baretail, but free and works great:
http://logexpert.codeplex.com/

they both allow you to filter using reg-ex on the fly, outputting the filtered lines to a part of the window, and you can click the line in the filtered box to get to the actual line in the original text. and of course, allow highlighting and colouring using reg-ex.

both are windows only unfortunately. i usually run android on a MAC, and share the log file created by adb with a windows machine that parses the log file on the fly using LogExpert.